# Matlab Stereo Camera Calibrator to C#.NET

Tags: c#, matlab, camera-calibration

Matlab side calibration function is ok , it works great. 
I made DLL via deploytool include this function.
This function returns camera calibration info.

```
function [ result ] = Calibrate()
imageFileNames1 = {'D:\left\l1.png',...
    'D:\left\l10.png',...
    'D:\left\l2.png',...
    'D:\left\l3.png',...
    'D:\left\l4.png',...
    'D:\left\l5.png',...
    'D:\left\l6.png',...
    'D:\left\l7.png',...
    'D:\left\l8.png',...
    'D:\left\l9.png',...
    };
imageFileNames2 = {'D:\right\r1.png',...
    'D:\right\r10.png',...
    'D:\right\r2.png',...
    'D:\right\r3.png',...
    'D:\right\r4.png',...
    'D:\right\r5.png',...
    'D:\right\r6.png',...
    'D:\right\r7.png',...
    'D:\right\r8.png',...
    'D:\right\r9.png',...
    };
[imagePoints, boardSize, imagesUsed] = detectCheckerboardPoints(imageFileNames1, imageFileNames2);
squareSize = 25;
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);
[stereoParams, pairsUsed, estimationErrors] = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints, worldPoints, ...
    'EstimateSkew', false, 'EstimateTangentialDistortion', false, ...
    'NumRadialDistortionCoefficients', 2, 'WorldUnits', 'mm');
result=stereoParams;
end
```

C# Side :

```
using StereoCameraCalibrator2;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                CalibrateAPI2 calibrate2 = new CalibrateAPI2(); 
                MWArray result =    calibrate2.Calibrate(); // this returns null all ways

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

Why return null? 
Another sample works normal such as rgb to image convertion. But calibration doesnt work. How can I solve this.

Comment: Does the code run in matlab?  To test code make simple matlab file that calls Calibrate.

Comment: function running correctly  in matlab , there is no problem in matlab side. I tested.

Comment: Where is the DllImport declaration.  It should be in the CalibrateAPI2 class. You didn't post that code and the error is probably in the class.

Comment: How to catch error in CalibrateAPI2 class. I am sure about  when I call calibrate2.Calibrate() , matlab function running.   because   I wrote a sample before this  , calibrate function include two parameters leftImages and righImages paths.  at C# side , ı send paths to matlab function function running but return null.  I catch error when I sent fail path (file not found error return matlab function) so I am sure matlab function running. How do I catch any error in CalibrateAPI class

Comment: Add a exception handler (try/catch) around call to Calibrate() in CalibrateAPI2.  The exception handler has e.Message and e.StackTrace.  The StackTrace will give more details.  The error is probably caused by a mismatch in the DllImport statement.

Comment: Ok I'lI try.  I have an question.  This 'Calibrate()' matlab function required matlab Computer Vision toolbox. Do I have to import any CV library when I make dll via deploytool command at matlab side or c# side.

Comment: You need to either have Matlab installed on the PC or install the matlab run time library.  The run time library doesn't require a matlab license.  You cannot pass a c# string to the matlab for the pathnames.  You must send a '\0' terminated byte[].  Use byte[] filename -= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filename + "\0");  Where filename is the c# string filename.